# Kendall Tau Distance Python Implementation with range [0,1]

Tags: python, scipy, scoring

Is there a Python implementation for Kendall Tau Distance Metric that produces scores in [0, 1] range and not in [-1,1]? The latter is already provided through scipy library.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an implementation of the [Kendall tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance), but as you mentioned, [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/index.html) does have a [Kendell tau correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) ([`scipy.stats.kendalltau`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kendalltau.html)).  It is important [not to confuse the two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance#Comparison_to_Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient), as a normalized distance of 0 is the same as a correlation of 1 and a normalized distance of 1 is the same as a correlation of -1.

I would write my derivation in math notation, but unfortunately, stackoverflow does not support mathjax

```
tau_dist := B/N
tau_coef := (A-B)/N
```

where A is the number of agreeing orderings, B is the number of disagreeing orderings, and N is the number of items (aka, `N = A + B`).  To convert a value of `tau_coef` to `tau_dist`, it turns out to be a linear relationship with negative slope.  The previous answer assumes a positive linear relationship, but the actual relationship is negative.

```
from scipy.stats import kendalltau

def _kendall_convert_coef_to_dist(tau_coef):
    '''Convert kendall correlation coefficient to normalized distance'''
    return (1 - tau_coef) / 2

def kendalldist(*args, **kwargs):
    '''Return the normalized Kendall tau distance (0 <= tau <= 1)
    This function wraps around scipy.stats.kendalltau()
    and forwards all arguments to that function.
    '''
    tau_coef, p_value = kendalltau(*args, **kwargs)
    return _kendall_convert_coef_to_dist(tau_coef)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with providing an existing implementation, but maybe this is sufficient for you.

You can just map the `[-1, 1]` to a `[0, 1]` range, without any effort.

Code could look like this:

```
def map_to_0_1(score):
    return (1+score) / 2

foo_scores = [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]
print('original range scores:     ', foo_scores)
print('scores mapped to new range:', list(map(map_to_0_1, foo_scores)))
```

**Output:**

```
original range scores:      [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]
scores mapped to new range: [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
```

This is just a linear mapping which shrinks the input proportionally to a `[0, 1]` range, of course you can also use different non-linear mappings.

I hope this helps.

Comment: [Kendall distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) is not to be confused with [Kendall rank coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) (distance of 0 is the same as rank coefficient of 1, distance of 1 is the same as rank coefficient -1).